# Is there any free software to create virtual floppy disks?

Tags: windows, gratis, windows-10

I want to make virtual floppy disks (1.44MB) for virtual machines, but can't find any freeware that an do that. I also want it to work with Windows 10 1709 (x64). Does such a software exist?

I found [this](http://vfd.sourceforge.net/) on SourceForge, but it does not work on x64 versions of Windows.

Comment: Do you want to create disk images or how to mount already existing images for use in a VM?

Comment: @Alejandro Software that can make disk images.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are doing some really complicated stuff with the VM's, or have a brain-dead hypervisor, a floppy disk image is just a raw filesystem image of the appropriate size (1.44MB in your case) and type (probably FA12 or FAT16 unless you're doing something really weird).

Because Microsoft still seems to think it's not something real people actually ever need to do, there's not any easy way to produce such files natively on Windows, but there's a really easy solution, create a file that's exactly 1440000 bytes long containing whatever random data you want (it could literally just be 1440000 spaces if you want), and then attach that file to the VM and format the virtual floppy disk from inside the VM.  Once you've done that, you can just copy that file to create new floppy disk images.

Comment: It worked, but, for seemingly no reason, it started giving unknown errors when I tried to make the disk over half full. The virtual floppy file is 1474560 bytes large, and the files were under 100KB.

Answer (score 1):

With [QEMU](https://www.qemu.org/) emulator you can simulate several perifericals. To emulate a floppy disk with read/write capabilities use the command:

```
qemu-system-i386 linux.img -fda fat:floppy:rw:/my_directory
```

Answer (score 1):

[winimage](https://www.winimage.com/)

Can manage virtual floppy disk.